# in-memory database with publish subscribe and query filter?

Tags: python, c++, publish-subscribe, in-memory, nosql

I am looking for a trading UI solution for my work. I require an in-memory database that can

- store table pattern data (rows and columns) with indexing capability.
- Provide publish and subscribe mechanism. There will be multiple subscribers to the topic/table.
- Query filter capability since every user will have different criteria for subscription.

I have found out a few technologies/options myself.

- **AMPS (60 East technologies):** The most efficient one. Provides pretty much everything I mentioned above. But this is a paid solution. It is column based storage and allows indexing as well.
- **Mongodb Tailable Cursor/Capped Collection:** This also provides query based subscription with open cursors, though it is not in-memory. Any thoughts on its performance. (I expect more than million rows with 100s of column)
- **Use simple pubsub mechanism** and perform query filter at client. But that would require unnecessary data flow which will result in security issues and performance bottleneck.

Any suggestion on the product or toolset ideal for such a scenario. Our client side is a Python/C++ UI with server side will have a mixture of C++/java/python components. All ideas are welcome.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite, maybe?  https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

I'm not exactly sure about your publish/subscribe mechanism requirements, but SQLite is used all over the place.

Though, to be honest, your in memory database seems like it's going to be huge ("I expect more than [a] million rows with 100s of column").